Quicksight joins is duplicating lines
I have 2 tables, One table(A) has columns accounts, original price and products and the other table(B) has account, product and updated price, table A has 10 rows and table B has 70 rows, I use left join on account to combine the two tables. Now I want to see the total of the original price, this has increased exponentially as the lines are getting duplicated to match the 70 lines... is there a way I can only filter on distinct values in Quick sight?

you could use Level Aware Calculation - Aggregation,to calculate the original price at the desired level of granularity

Create a calculated field with below expression :

  maxOver(sum({original_price}), [{account}], PRE_AGG)
This expression calculates the sum of original_price for each distinct account, effectively removing duplicates.

you can then use this in your visual to join with table B.

